# I want to compare a timestamp to the current time minus a month

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pulling a timestamp called expiry_date from a database and I need to check if said time is less than a month from the current date.

```
db.collection('inventory/clubs/MUCK').where("expiry_date", "<=", Date.now()-2592000000) //check the database for every date less than a month from the present.
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot){
    var count = 0;
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
        count++; //increment for every hit.
    });
    console.log(count);
});
```

This is my attempt so far, it simply logs a count of 0, but there are items in the collection which are below a month from the present.

Comment: A mandatory reminder that not every month is 30 days, and not every day is 24 hours, and not every hour is 60 seconds.

Comment: not sure if my thought is correct, but I would do something such as getting today's date minus / plus 1 for the month then do the compare / between as needed

Comment: In what format is your `expiry_date` stored in db. Is it in milliseconds format or DD-MM-YYYY format or something else?

Comment: @zerkms It doesn't need to be exact, it's set for 30 days before the expiry, which is fine for what I need it for

Comment: @Dora that's what I'm trying to do, just needed to understand why it wasn't working

Comment: @kapilpandey 24 December 2019  at 11:39:00 AM UTC is how it's written in the firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Firestore, you can't compare a timestamp type field to an integer value as you're doing now.  You will need to build either a Firestore Timestamp or JavaScript Date object for the query.

```
where("expiry_date", "<=", new Date(Date.now() - some_delta))
```

Comment: And is that delta just a integer in milliseconds to subtract from the date?

Comment: According to the documentation for the Date object, yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date